# Can't perform Really Simple Firebase Database update using Angular 4 and Firebase 2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

The web app I'm building is incredibly simple, and uses Angular 4 and firebase2. It lists a table with songs (Title, Artist, <3 icon and number of likes)

I made an object/array on Firebase with the list of of songs, each being an object with the 3 aforementioned properties. I am trying to make it so that when a user clicks on the heart of a song, the number of likes goes up by one, but none of the functions I've tried seem to work. Below are my attempts at this addLike function, as well as the resulting error, and below that is the full code of my html template, and component, and data structure. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
addLike(index){
this.songs.update(index, { likes: this.songs[index] + 1 });

} 

//(23,1): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

addLike(index){
this.songs[index].update({likes: this.songs[index] + 1 });
} 
//ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined
```

Here is the full code

```html
//COMPONENT HTML
<div> TEST </div>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Likes</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let song of songs | async ; let i  = index">
<td>{{ song.title }}</td>
<td>{{ song.artist }}</td>
<td>{{ song.likes }}
 
            <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"  *ngIf="song.likes < 1"></i>
         <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" *ngIf="song.likes >= 1"></i>
<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" (click)="addLike(i)" ></i>

</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

```js
//COMPONENT TS

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule,AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})


export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Oxcord';


  songs: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
   constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.songs = db.object('/songs');
  }
  
  addLike(index){
this.songs[index].update({likes: this.songs[index] + 1 });

} 



}
```

```js
{
  "songs" : [ {
    "artist" : "J Cole",
    "likes" : 3,
    "title" : "No Role Modelz"
  }, {
    "artist" : "Michael Jackson",
    "likes" : 8,
    "title" : "Thriller"
  }, {
    "artist" : "Meek Mill",
    "likes" : 0,
    "title" : "Trash"
  }, {
    "artist" : "Kendrick",
    "likes" : 6,
    "title" : "Humble"
  }, {
    "artist" : "Missy",
    "likes" : 4,
    "title" : "Work It"
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're updating your local `songs` property. You should update your database instead:

```
addLike(id: string, likes: number): void {
  this.db.object(`/songs/${id}`).update({ likes: likes + 1 });
}
```

That way, you can call the `addLike` method in your songs list passing the song `key` and the current amount of likes:

```
<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" (click)="addLike(song.$key, song.likes)" ></i>
```

Then, in your method, you can update the number of likes at that song location in your database.

See the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md#updating-data) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just tried your code, and now I'm getting the following error: ERROR in ...../oxcord/src/app/app.component.ts (25,8): Property 'db' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
webpack: Failed to compile. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you injecting `db` in your constructor? `constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}`. Can you create a Plunker, please?

Comment: My code is exactly as above, there's db but no "private" and it seems to work fine (except for the update fn below it of course)
  songs: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
   constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.songs = db.object('/songs');
  } But yea I can make a plunker if it helps of course. I'll be at work soon and I'll do it then

Comment: Sorry but I'm having really tough time trying to figure out how to make this work on plunkr. (I'm relatively new to programming in general to be honest) here are all the files in my git repository. [git repository here](https://github.com/jonnyk20/oxcord) Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just an update: I tried using FirebaseListObservable instead, using your function in the export class AppCompnent: addLike(id: string, likes: number): void {
  this.db.list(`/songs/${id}`).update({ likes: likes +1 });
 
}
// The error I get says: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Comment: Finally Got it working! Thank you! This was the winner: addLike(id: string, likes: number): void {
 this.db.list('/songs/').update(id,{ likes: likes +1 });
}